Google generativeai 403 Request had insufficient authentication scopes. [reason: "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT"
I have tried the simple POC for generativeai on its own to do 'generate_content' and it works. Now I am trying to integrate the generativeai to existing project and just trying to get the model only and it is throwing this.
import google.generativeai as genai

genai.configure(api_key=GOOGLE_GEMINI_API)
model_name = "gemini-1.5-flash"
model = genai.GenerativeModel(model_name=model_name)
response = model.generate_content('Hello there.')


# Error
google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 Request had insufficient authentication scopes. [reason: "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT"
domain: "googleapis.com"
metadata {
  key: "service"
  value: "generativelanguage.googleapis.com"
}
metadata {
  key: "method"
  value: "google.ai.generativelanguage.v1beta.GenerativeService.GenerateContent"
}


I am suspecting that there is a conflict of ADC (Application Default Credential) issue. Cause the existing project is configured with ADC. However I want to leave it alone and I want google gemini API key to be a separate module and I don't want it tied to existing project. (Nor I want yet another google cloud project to manage at this point.) Still, getting google gemini key, it has created google cloud project nonetheless. Are there a way to make generativeai API not picking up the credential from the existing ADC ? I am using the Python library. I need help from google cloud platform oauth credential expert on this infamous area, I think.
Here is the google generativeai code on github
https://github.com/google-gemini/generative-ai-python/blob/v0.7.0/google/generativeai/client.py#L272-L311

Where do you have GOOGLE_GEMINI_API set?  Was the api key created on Ai studio?

It was created in AI Studio with a different account even.

Account shouldnt matter as long as its a valid api key.  Can you do a print(GOOGLE_GEMINI_API)  i have only seen this error when i am having issues not reading the ENV var properly

Hi Linda, you are absolutely spot on. GOOGLE_GEMINI_API environment variable is not in the PyCharm runtime environment. I have checked that in the linux shell before with echo $GOOGLE_GEMINI_API and it is there. so I thought that I have done my due diligence ... I have to restart the PyCharm for that. (Are there any other way?) Anyway, please write an actual answer and I will mark it answer.

Every time i have seen "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT" error it has been due to the fact that i wasn't not sending an api key or that the env far that I was sending was null.
genai.configure(api_key=GOOGLE_GEMINI_API)

Personally i normal use a .env file for my env vars and use pip python-dotenv
I believe though that if you are loading from a linux environment you can use
my_var = os.environ.get('MY_ENV_VAR')

As I have personally had this issue before.  I have submitted a feature request to the client library #450
